# Нужна ли запятая? Не понять, есть ли уточнение или нет

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, уточнения

> Давай встретимся сегодня() в 8 часов вечера.

Вообще, запятую здесь не хочется ставить, но ведь можно объяснить её постановку уточняющим значением: когда? - сегодня, когда именно? - 8 часов вечера. Буду очень благодарен за разъяснение!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Отношения между обстоятельствами могут быть однородными, неоднородными и уточняющими. Интонация, соответственно, тоже: интонация простого предложения, перечислительная или исключительная (при обособлении).

Выбор делается **по семантике (по конкретной ситуации**), здесь авторское решение.

**Неоднородные отношения:** указываются две разные неоднородные координаты (день и время).

**Уточнение:** Называется день (основная координата), а время уточняется.

Однородные отношения для этого предложения не подходят

Answer (score 2):

Вне специфического контекста запятая *не* нужна, но она может понадобиться, например, в случае противопоставления имеющегося "сегодня" другой дате, предложенной ранее собеседником. Тогда время суток может стать *уточнением* к акцентируемой (интонационно и пунктуацией) дате:

> - Может быть, *завтра* встретимся по этому поводу?
> - Давай [лучше] встретимся *сегодня*, в 8 часов вечера.

Comment: Да, но как, по-вашему, объясняется отсутствие этой запятой?

Comment: Объясняется нейтральностью высказываения ввиду отсутствия дополнительного контекста. Это простое обозначение времени, аналогичное выражению "сегодня вечером".